# Script for running some task in a terminal and then some other commands in same terminal but different tab?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I am working on some Ruby on Rails project .

Everyday I have to open a terminal(**in MAC**) and do following steps :-

1. cd to ~/folder1 .
   start  service1
2. open new tab in terminal .
   cd to ~/folder2 .
   start  service2
3. open new tab in terminal .
   cd to ~/folder3 .
   start  service3

   and so on for 10 services .

I want to make a single scirpt in mac that will do these things just on double clicking it or running it from terminal .

I have tried many things using shell script but not getting a nice solution .
Plzz help !!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html).

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    repeat while contents of selected tab of window 1 starts with linefeed
        delay 0.01
    end repeat
    do script "echo a" in window 1
end tell
```

This should execute `echo a` in a new tab in Terminal. However, the AppleScript-support of Terminal is not too good. I recommend using [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com) instead. It not only has a much better support for AppleScript but comes with some other great features.
For examples on how to write AppleScripts for iTerm have a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/AppleScript).